# How can we decode transaction and event data shown on blockchain explorer

Tags: go-ethereum, explorers, epirus

How can we decode transaction and event data shown on blockchain explorer. I have tried couple of blockchain explorer like (epirus-free, blockscout) but they are showing only encoded values of events and functions....how can I show human readable values in my blockexplorer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just go to any hex to text website and paste your hex text.

http://string-functions.com/hex-string.aspx[enter link description here](http://string-functions.com/hex-string.aspx)

Then the messages will be in human readable format.